# cakephp file download link

Tags: php, cakephp

I've encountered a problem I'm trying to solve for more than two days now: I've built a Website using cakephp and everything is working just fine but I got stuck when I tried to implement download links to files stored under `APP_DIR/someFolder/someFile.zip`.

How do I set download links to files inside `someFolder`? I often stumbled over "Media Views" I tried implementing them but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Besides is there no easier way to make files downloadable?

Comment: If you're using Apache, you can force download by adding a `.htaccess` inside the 'download' directory. See some examples here: http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/30/forcing-a-download-with-apache-and-htaccess and http://www.timewasters-place.com/how-to-force-file-downloading-with-htaccess/ This way you don't need to serve the files to download via PHP

Comment: What about placing them at APP_DIR/webroot/someFolder/?

Comment: @sємsєм You're right (didn't notice the files weren't inside the webroot). Although only placing them in a public directory will not automatically force them to download (e.g. if the file is a JPG). Adding a .htaccess that sends 'download' headers, will make it easier for people to 'download' the files in stead of *viewing* them inside the browser. Although it's possible to do so view PHP (see the answer below), this is not always ideal, especially for large files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Media Views is deprecated since version 2.3. You should use [Sending files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) instead.

Check out this minimal example in your controller:

```
public function download($id) {
    $path = $this->YourModel->aMagicFunctionThatReturnsThePathToYourFile($id);
    $this->response->file($path, array(
        'download' => true,
        'name' => 'the name of the file as it should appear on the client\'s computer',
    ));
    return $this->response;
}
```

The first parameter of `$this->response->file` is relative to your `APP` directory. So calling `$this->response->file('someFolder' . DS . 'someFile.zip')` will download the file `APP/someFolder/someFile.zip`.

“Sending files” requires at least CakePHP version 2.0. Please also consider taking a look at the Cookbook link above.

---

If you are running an older version of CakePHP you should use **Media Views** as you already mentioned in your question. Use this code and refer to [Media Views (Cookbook)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html).

Here's the same method for older versions:

```
public function download($id) {
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $path = $this->YourModel->aMagicFunctionThatReturnsThePathToYourFile($id);
    // in this example $path should hold the filename but a trailing slash
    $params = array(
        'id' => 'someFile.zip',
        'name' => 'the name of the file as it should appear on the client\'s computer',
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => 'zip',
        'path' => $path
    );
    $this->set($params);
}
```

Comment: hmm... I implemented it the way you described but I'm gettiing:
Call to undefined method CakeResponse::files()...

I serched it in the Documentation and couldn't find a file() method but id did find a Download Method but I  can not make it work with Ether.. :(

Comment: @sємsєм: I would like to keep outside the Webroot If Possible... It's Not senetive Data But I would feel better if these files Arent there for the wole world to Grab copy and play arround With...

Comment: @MichaelHofmair: which CakePHP version do you use? As mentioned in my answer you need at least CakePHP version 2.0. But I edited my answer and added explanations for older versions.

Comment: currently I'm running 2.3.1

Comment: @MichaelHofmair with version 2.3.1 you can certainly use `$this->response->file` (the top example). Concerning one of your comments above: If you get an “undefined method” error, you probably misspelled the method's name. The name is `$this->response->file` – no plural of “file”. Just copy and paste my code above. I already tested it. For debugging don't forget to set `$path`. Use `$path = 'someFolder/someFile.zip';`. Cake will let you know if the file exists or doesn't.

Comment: Now I feel Bad. I Honestly don't know for how many hours I've sat if front of this damned Action actually trying to debug a mispelled Method Name...sice I originally copyed the Download Action directly from the Cakephp Cookbook I cant Imagine How I.
THX Again To Everybody Who Contributed!
AND Special Thx to Jan who has prooven abnormal high tollerance to my own apparent stupidity. :-/ *facepalm*

Comment: I am glad that I could help you :-) To show your appreciation please consider marking my answer as “accepted” and giving it an vote up. Thanks.

Comment: sorry vote Up requires 15 reputation I dont yet have sa a Newbee :/  I'm only 4 points short damn :( ... but I'll swing by later when I have them... if by then it is still possible to do so...

Comment: @Jan i have similar question in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222047/cakephp-file-download-was-not-found-or-not-readable please do take a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right way to generate download link in **CakePHP 3**

Place this function in AppController or Write a component and then call from other controllers.

> Make sure to change the content-type as per the download file

```
public function downloadResponse() {
    return $this->response
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=1')
        ->withHeader('Expires', 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT')
        ->withHeader('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' PDT')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'cache, must-revalidate')
        ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
        ->withFile($filePath, ['download' => true]);
}
```