# CakePHP 3 - Downloading regardless of the host and project name

Tags: cakephp, download, cakephp-3.0

On any particular View, if I include this link:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Download', ['controller' => 'Uploads', 'action' => 'download',$upload->id]) ?>
```

A user can download a file based on the `$upload->id` provided.

I'm using this as my download function in my Uploads controller:

```
$upload = $this->Uploads->find('all')->first();
$filePath = '\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\uploads'; //file path to where the uploaded file is
$this->response->file($filePath . DS . $upload->name,
    array('download' => true, 'name' => $upload->name)); //finds the corresponding name attribute in the Uploads table of the database, finds a matching name in the uploads directory and then downloads that file.

$this->set(compact('upload'));
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to be able to have the file path be more flexible. In my `config.php`, I have set two variables called `$host` and `$basepath` to refer to the web host (localhost) and the project name (project) respectively. I pass these variables to the AppController, and they can be accessed by any View.

But I can't seem to use these variables in the `$filePath` variable of the download function, so if I or anyone else were to change hosts or the project name, instead of being able to simply change `config.php`, I or anyone else would have to go and find this and change it as well (and if I had multiple download functions in multiple controllers, they'd have to go and change each and every one of them).

Comment: Do you mean you want to provide file location path on easier way ? If so you can use base url or define that path as constant somewhere .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the CakePHP global constants. You can easily access the path to your webroot by using `WWW_ROOT`.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Comment: When I try to use WWW_ROOT as follows: `$filePath = WWW_ROOT.'uploads'.DS.$upload->name;`, I get this error upon attempting to download (sample file being downloaded is a blank Excel file called Book1.xlsx: `The requested file C:\xampp\htdocs\project\src\C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\uploads\Book1.xlsx\Book1.xlsx was not found or not readable`. The WWW_ROOT seems to try and go into the source code first, then go back out again before going towards the correct directory.

Comment: @mistaq When you debug your $filePath does that look correct ? If so see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222047/cakephp-file-download-was-not-found-or-not-readable

Comment: debug($filePath) gives this: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\'. But in any case, I found my answer from that, and changed $filePath to `WWW_ROOT.DS.'uploads';